# Синхронный запрос Angular с Websockets

Tags: angularjs, websocket

Rails 4.2.0, gem websocket-rails (0.7.0), AngularJS (CoffeeScript).
Есть таблица events нужно вытащить список событий и потом его фильтровать.

Инициализирую соединение:

```
dispatcher = new WebSocketRails(websocket_url)
```

Запускаю функцию get_events:

```
dispatcher.trigger('event.get_events', true, events_success, events_failure)
```

Выполняется success

```
events_success = (data) ->
  $rootScope.events = data.events
```

Путем простого вывода в консоль, можно заметить, что выполнение скрипта продолжается не дожидаясь выполнения функции и отрабатывания success.

В итоге страница загрузилась, а списка событий (events) на странице нет, покликали по вкладкам, angular обновил данные и вот он, список появился.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как же дождаться выполнения функции и её success'а? Или может быть тогда как заставить angular после выполнения success перерисовать список?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробовал в success написать:

```
$rootScope.$apply ->
  $rootScope.events = data.events
```

И сработало. Данные сразу видны. Не знаю насколько это правильно.

Comment: Стоит проверять `$rootScope.$$phase` на наличие значения, когда пустое, значит надо `...$apply`, иначе находишься в digestion loop и всё само обновится.